# Use custom typehandler on resulttype in myBatis

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

In our project we use mybatis and have a custom type handler on strings that strip html and other things from the result by default. We can override this by setting a different typehandler in the resultmap.

However I now have a situation where dynamic querys are used in a select so something like this

```
<select id="executeQuery" resultType="String">
${sql}
</select>
```

Now I dont want the result to be stripped of its html, so I want to use a custom typehandler. Normally I would do this in a result map, but the problem is I dont know the name of the column that will be used in the query. Is there a solution for this problem where I can use another typehandler on this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others running into this problem. In the end I used the following workaround:

`SELECT (${sql}) AS value`

This has some limitation in what kind of queries can be used in the sql statement though. For example in ms sql a query with an order by without a top, offset or for xml cannot be used.